# Whole number to comma separated price - SQL Server & SSMS

Tags: sql, sql-server

I couldn't find any answer to my question and I hope you can help me out. I've been asked to create a revenue report, however, I'm dealing with an old poorly optimized database. It sounds like a simple thing but I cannot find any solution to  the below issue.

Basically, some prices are being shown in the following format:

```
22400
```

What I need is to show these values in this format format: `22,40`

Any suggestions? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [format](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/format-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) function :

```
select format(prices, '0,000')
from table t;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
convert(decimal(38, 2), convert(decimal, 22400) / 1000);
```

to convert it to a `decimal(38, 2)`. Possibly lower the precision (`38`) if you don't need that much.

Answer (score 0):

First you have to convert this price(ex: 22400) from one datatype to 'money' datatype using CAST function.

and then CONVERT money to character

references - 
1) https://www.techonthenet.com/sql_server/functions/convert.php
2) https://www.techonthenet.com/sql_server/functions/cast.php

Syntax :
CONVERT(nvarchar, CAST(price AS money), 1)